# terraform disable validation

Tags: azure, terraform

We are trying to provision [azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_data_lake_storage_gen2](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory_linked_service_data_lake_storage_gen2) and wanted to set the url to a parameterised variable in ADF.  It is possible to do this in the Azure Data Factory user interface however, the resource provider's url component forces us to use https: to pass its validation so we cannot put in a parameter.

url = "@Dataset().ST_URL"

Is there a way to disable the url check in terraform for this one field?

```
 resource "azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_data_lake_storage_gen2" "example" {
  name                  = "example"
  data_factory_id       = azurerm_data_factory.example.id
  service_principal_id  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.client_id
  service_principal_key = "exampleKey"
  tenant                = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
  url                   = "@Dataset().ST_URL"
}
```

This line appears to force a requirement for https:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/main/internal/services/datafactory/data_factory_linked_service_data_lake_storage_gen2_resource.go#L55

Comment: What is your Terraform code?

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: So you already have an `https://` prefix somewhere else and Terraform is complaining because you are not providing that prefix?

Comment: indeed yes.  Even if we try form format("https://", "@Dataset().ST_URL") it still expects a host.

Comment: I don't think validation can be skipped as it is a requirement by the Azure API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage?tabs=data-factory#service-principal-authentication.

Comment: However, if you know the type of value `@Dataset().ST_URL` is returning, you might be able to derive it by using an external data source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source

Comment: @Dataset().ST_URL is not a parameter for terraform. it is used by ADF to make our pipeline generic

Comment: You need to raise an issue on the provider. If you are certain that the URL does not need to be HTTPS, then the maintainers will likely agree, and then you or they can PR. If they disagree that HTTP is allowed, then an explanation will follow, and you can move forward with that route also.